Unity slider only updating in increments of .01 despite number of increments assigned
I'm a beginner programmer who's been following a tutorial from 2018 (uploaded on YouTube in mid-2023) on how to create a turn-based battle system based on the original Final Fantasy 7. I am currently using the 2022.3.23f1 version of Unity. In this part of the tutorial, we are setting up the UI elements - including limit and time gauges that will let the player know when their turn is active and if they can do unique special attacks.
My issue is that the limit and time bars are not properly displaying the information assigned to them. For instance, if a character has a speed of 4, the time bar increases by 4 increments of .01--or roughly 4%--before stopping. The limit bar does not increase at all. This shows the program is logging the data. It just isn't correctly outputting the information.
Here's what the tutorial said to create:
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterData characterData;
    public CharacterControl targetData;

    private void Start()
    {
        characterData.Init();

        characterData._target = targetData.characterData;

        StartCoroutine(characterData.CharacterLoop());
    }
    private void Update()
    {


        if (characterData.ActionReady)
        {
            Debug.Log("Is ready to attack");
            if (characterData.characterTeam == CharacterData.CharacterTeam.Friendly && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Debug.Log(characterData.charName + " did an action");

                if (characterData._target.CanAttackTarget)
                {
                    characterData.Attack();
                }


            }
        }
        }
    
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[System.Serializable]
public class CharacterData
{
    public string charName;

    [Space(10)]

    public CharacterUIData charUI;

    [Space(10)]

    public int maxHealth, curHealth, maxMagicPoints, curMagicPoints;

    [Space(10)]

    public float maxLimitPoints, curLimitPoints, maxSpeed, curSpeed;

    [Space(10)]

    public CharacterState characterState;
    public CharacterTeam characterTeam;

    [Space(10)]

    public UnityEvent onAttack;
    public UnityEvent onWasAttacked;
    public bool playerAttacked;

    [Space(16)]

    public CharacterData _target;

    public void Init()
    {
        if(characterTeam == CharacterTeam.Friendly)
        charUI.Init(maxHealth, curHealth, maxMagicPoints, curMagicPoints, charName, maxSpeed, maxLimitPoints);

        onAttack.AddListener(CharacterAttack);
        onWasAttacked.AddListener(CharacterWasAttacked);

        characterState = CharacterState.Idle;
    }

    public void Attack()
    {
        onAttack.Invoke();

        //TEMPORARY ATTACK.
        _target.Damage(10);
    }

    public void Damage(int damageAmount)
    {
        curHealth -= damageAmount;

        if (curHealth <= 0)
        {
            curHealth = 0;
            characterState = CharacterState.Defeated;
        }

        //Handling Limit Bar progression.
        if (characterTeam == CharacterTeam.Friendly)
        {
            curLimitPoints += 5;
            curLimitPoints = Mathf.Clamp(curLimitPoints, 0, maxLimitPoints);

            charUI.UpdateTimeBar(curLimitPoints);
        }

        onWasAttacked.Invoke();
    }

    public bool CanBeAttacked
    {
        get
        {
            return characterState == CharacterState.Idle || characterState == CharacterState.Ready;
        }
    }
    public bool CanAttackTarget
    {
        get
        {
            return _target.characterState == CharacterState.Idle || _target.characterState == CharacterState.Ready;
        }
    }

    public bool ActionReady
    {
        get
        {
            return curSpeed >= maxSpeed;
        }
    }

    void CharacterAttack()
    {
        Debug.Log(_target.charName + " was attacked.");
        playerAttacked = false;
        curSpeed = 0;
    }

    void CharacterWasAttacked()
    {
        Debug.Log(charName + " was attacked.");
    }

    public IEnumerator CharacterLoop()
    {
        while (characterState != CharacterState.Defeated)
        {

            // action-ready mechanic
            if (curSpeed >= maxSpeed)
            {
                curSpeed = maxSpeed;
                characterState = CharacterState.Ready;
            }
            else
            {
                //Increase curSpeed
                curSpeed += Time.deltaTime;
                charUI.UpdateTimeBar(curSpeed);
                characterState = CharacterState.Idle;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class CharacterUIData
    {

        public RowUI physicUI;
        public int placeInUI = 1;

        public void Init(int maxHealth, int curHealth, int maxMagic, int curMagic, string charName, float maxLimit, float maxSpeed)
        {
            placeInUI = UIManager.curUICount;

            if (placeInUI == 1)
            {
                //Do not spawn a second row. Use the first.
                physicUI = UIManager.Instance.defaultRowUI;
            }
            else
            {
                //Spawn a new row.
                UIManager.Instance.SpawnRow(out physicUI);
            }



            //Health Slider setup
            physicUI.healthSlider.maxValue = maxHealth;
            physicUI.healthSlider.value = curHealth;
            physicUI.healthUI.text = curHealth + "/ " + maxHealth.ToString();

            //MP Slider setup
            physicUI.magicSlider.maxValue = curMagic;
            physicUI.magicSlider.value = curMagic;
            physicUI.magicUI.text = curMagic.ToString();

            //Character Info setup
            physicUI.characterUI.text = charName.ToString();

            //Limit and Time Bar setup.
            physicUI.limitSlider.maxValue = maxLimit;
            physicUI.limitSlider.value = 0f;

            physicUI.speedSlider.maxValue = maxSpeed;
            physicUI.speedSlider.value = 0f;

            UIManager.curUICount++;
        }

        public void UpdateTimeBar(float curProgress)
        {
            physicUI.speedSlider.value = curProgress;
        }

        public void UpdateLimitBar(float curProgress)
        {
            physicUI.limitSlider.value = curProgress;
        }
    }

    public enum CharacterTeam
    {
        Friendly,
        Enemy
    }
    public enum CharacterState
    {
        Loading,
        Idle,
        Ready,
        Attacked,
        Attacking,
        Defeated
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
public class RowUI : MonoBehaviour

{
    public Slider healthSlider;
    public TextMeshProUGUI healthUI;

    public Slider magicSlider;
    public TextMeshProUGUI magicUI;

    public Slider limitSlider;
    public Slider speedSlider;

    public TextMeshProUGUI characterUI;
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static UIManager Instance;

    public Transform rowHolder;
    public Transform nameHolder;

    [Header("UI Prefabs")]
    public GameObject rowPrefab;
    public GameObject namePrefab;

    [Header("First Player UI")]
    public RowUI defaultRowUI;

    public static int curUICount = 1;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    public void SpawnRow(out RowUI processedUI)
    {
        //Instantiate a row inside the row holder.
        GameObject tmpRow = Instantiate(rowPrefab);
        tmpRow.transform.SetParent(rowHolder, false);
        RowUI RowTmpInfo = tmpRow.GetComponent<RowUI>();

        //Instantiate a name inside the name holder.
        GameObject tmpName = Instantiate(namePrefab);
        tmpName.transform.SetParent(nameHolder, false);
        TextMeshProUGUI txtName = tmpName.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();


        RowTmpInfo.characterUI = txtName;

        processedUI = RowTmpInfo;
    }
}

The limit and time bar setup section is where things get interesting (at least, to me). I attempted several fixes I found online, such as: changing the gauges' values inside Unity, turning on whole numbers, etc. None of them worked. However, when I went in an manually assigned values inside the limit and time bar setups, they worked correctly in-game. This leads me to believe there is some issue with the way this code is processing the variables.
The time gauge definitely knows it should stop after a set number of increments. It even fills entirely if I increase the value to 100 in my Unity browser. It just isn't adjusting those increments correctly when using the maxSpeed variable. I'm guessing there's a similar issue with the limit gauge.
Oddly enough, the hit point and magic point bars work perfectly and scale accordingly. As far as I can tell, they're setup in similar fashion. The only difference is the speed and limit gauges have that additional curProgress float attached. Could that be the issue?
I've been at this for several hours now, and if anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Can you provide more info on the values of the related variables?

Certainly! Basically, the entire thing is separated into 4 files: Character Control, Character Data, RowUI, and UI Manager. Here is the code in its entirety up to this point (posted in the above edit)


your magic slider has incorrect maxValue (which makes it weird you say it works).
You try to update the timebar with currLimitPoints in Damage, instead of updating the limit bar.
You use Clamp nicely in the limit points, but not for the speed.

